# uinavigationcontroller inside of a uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a 4 tab based app. I need to add a navigation controller to one of the tabs, so I can drill down a table.
I already have code for the viewcontroller, so I am trying to avoid changing anything, except adding a navigationcontroller to one of the viewcontrollers.
Is that possible?
UIViewController > NavigationController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the TabBarViewController init where you add the viewcontrollers add:

```
    MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: viewController];
    navController.tabBarItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyTitle" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"] tag:3] autorelease];
    //add navController to tabbar controllers
    [navController release];
    [viewController release];
```

so you basically have UINavigationViewController as a tabbar item and it holds your viewcontroller inside. It's a better approach than adding a UINavigatonController over a UITabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the reverse. Set the tab's Controller type as navigation controller and set your view controller as navigation controller's view controller.